# Renaming model association attributes in Rails JSON serialization?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, serialization, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an existing Rails 3 application, to which I am adding a JSON API.  We have a `Vendor` ActiveRecord model, and an `Employee` ActiveRecord model.  An `Employee` belongs to a `Vendor`.  In the API, we want to include an `Employee`'s `Vendor` in the JSON serialization.  For example:

```
# Employee as JSON, including Vendor
:employee => {
    # ... employee attributes ...
    :vendor => {
        # ... vendor attributes ...
    }
}
```

That's easy enough.  However, I have a business requirement that the public API not expose the internal model names.  That is, to the outside world, it needs to seem as though the `Vendor` model is actually called `Business`:

```
# Employee as JSON, including Vendor as Business
:employee => {
    # ... employee attributes ...
    :business => {
        # ... vendor attributes ...
    }
}
```

This is easy to do for the top-level object.  That is, I could call `@employee.as_json(:root => :dude_who_works_here)` to rename `Employee` to `DudeWhoWorksHere` in the JSON.  But what about for included associations?  I have tried a few things without success:

```
# :as in the association doesn't work
@employee.as_json(:include => {:vendor => {:as => :business}})

# :root in the association doesn't work
@employee.as_json(:include => {:vendor => {:root => :business}})

# Overriding Vendor's as_json doesn't work (at least, not in a association)
    # ... (in vendor.rb)
    def as_json(options)
        super(options.merge({:root => :business}))
    end
    # ... elsewhere
    @employee.as_json(:include => :vendor)
```

The only other idea I have is to manually rename the key, something like this:

```
# In employee.rb
def as_json(options)
    json = super(options)
    if json.key?(:vendor)
        json[:business] = json[:vendor]
        json.delete(:vendor)
    end
    return json
end
```

But that seems inelegant.  I'm hoping there's a cleaner, more Rails-y way to do what I want.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Trying to generate complex JSON with the built-in options for as_json is clumsy. I would override `as_json` in your models, and not bother with calling `super` at all. Make up your own option keys for `as_json` to control what you want to include in the Hash.

```
# employee.rb
def as_json(options = {})
  json = {:name => name, ...} # whatever info you want to expose
  json[:business] = vendor.as_json(options) if options[:include_vendor]
  json
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue, so I modified the `as_json` to also run a recursive method to scan through the options, and switch the associations' names for the alias names. Anyhow, it works for my app, might could work for yours.

```
def self.test_serializer
  as_json(
    {
      :include => {
        :contact_info => {as: :contact_info_attributes}
      }
    }
  )
end

def as_json(options={})
  data = super(options)
  data = as_json_associations_alias_fix(options, data)
  return data
end

def as_json_associations_alias_fix options, data, opts = {}
  if options[:include].present?
    options[:include].each do |include_key, include_hash|
      data_key = include_key.to_s
      if include_hash[:as].present?
        alias_name = include_hash[:as]
        data[alias_name.to_s] = data[include_key.to_s]# if !data.is_a?(Array)
        data.delete(include_key.to_s)# if !data.is_a?(Array)
        data_key = alias_name.to_s
      end
      # Handle to-one association here, else handle the to-many association.
      if !data[data_key].is_a?(Array)
        data[data_key] = as_json_associations_alias_fix(include_hash, data[data_key])
      else
        data[data_key].each_with_index do |value,i|
          data[i] = as_json_associations_alias_fix(include_hash, value)
        end
      end
    end
  end
  return data
end
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's a sneaky way of doing it. Create a model called Business mapped to the vendors table:

```
class Business < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_table_name "vendors"
end
```

Now add a belongs_to on Employee:

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :vendor
  belongs_to :business, :foreign_key => :vendor_id
  ...
end
```

Call `to_json` on `Employee` passing in the "virtual" association as an option:

```
 Employee.first.to_json(:only=>:name,:include=>:business)
 # "{\"employee\":{\"name\":\"Curly\",\"business\":{\"name\":\"Moe's Garage\"}}}"
```

Comment: Yeah, I hadn't thought of that before, that is pretty sneaky.  I don't really want to have 2 separate models for the same data, though.  Seems like it would be too easy to create a new Business and miss out on any Vendor validations I have, for example.